# Changing button image (or color) on click

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, button, colors

I have a 10x10 Hex Game board which consists of hexagonal buttons. I am trying to change the color of the hexagons when user clicks on them. I tried lots of things but my buttons are always purple.

I tried to use the blue,black,red hexagons but weirdly every single one is purple when I use them as button backgrounds.

[image: When I use this black hexagon (or any other color) it is purple in the game.][image: ]]

XML for one button(I have 100 of these):

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button00"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/hexagon"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.300" />
```

I tried the following functions

```
buttons[finalI][finalJ].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#666bff")); //hexagons becomes squares, but still purple.
```

```
buttons[finalI][finalJ].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hexagonblue); //still purple
```

How can I change the colors of buttons and why all the buttons are purple even though I upload different colors of png hexagons?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but everything is solved after I used androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton instead of regular Button.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/button72"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/hexagon"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.218"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.722" />
```

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button72"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/hexagon"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.218"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.722" />
```